# Is it possible to create a nested variable?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

Not sure if this is possible, but the help I have received previously has been tremendous so what can it hurt.

I have a script that works great to import information from a google spreadsheet to my calendar. The problem is that I have 3 different columns of information (that I would like to keep separate for other purposes) that I would like to have imported into the description of my calendar. This might not be the right questions, but is there a way to create a nested variable that would import all 3 row/columns?

This is the script I have, but would be amazing if I could import row[6][8][9] into the description...

```js
function importCalendar() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headerRows = 2;  // Number of rows of header info (to skip)
var range = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = range.getValues();
var calId = "CALENDAR ID";
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
if (i < headerRows) continue; // Skip header row(s)
var row = data[i];
var startDate = row[0];  // First column
var title = row[3];           // Second column
var location = row[4];
var description = row[6];
var id = row[7];              // 8th column == eventId
var advancedArgs ={description: description, location: location};
// Check if event already exists, update it if it does
try {
  var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(id);
}
catch (e) {
  // do nothing - we just want to avoid the exception when event doesn't exist
}
if (!event) {
  var newEvent = cal.createAllDayEvent(title, new Date(startDate), advancedArgs).getId();
  row[7] = newEvent;  // Update the data array with event ID
}
else {
  event.setTitle(title);
  event.setDescription(description);
  event.setLocation(location);
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
  event.setRecurrence(recurrence, new Date(startDate));
}
debugger;
}
// Record all event IDs to spreadsheet
range.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Could you not just concatenate the rows? Perhaps split with new lines? My javascript is weak but... `var description = [row[6],row[8],row[9]].join('\n')`

Comment: Thats awesome!! Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: Did it work for you then?

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Exactly what I needed, thank you!!

Comment: Hey, Mary... don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) answers that have helped you. Once you have the necessary reputation, you can also upvote any helpful answers or questions. Those actions are what reward the folks volunteering their time here! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well you can certainly make a 2-Dimensional array, or rather an n-Dimensional array.  Take the following:

```
var table = [['Fruits', 'Veggies', 'SomethingElse'], ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach'], ['Carrot', 'Cucumber', 'Raddish'], [['Animals', 'People'], ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Bear'], ['Weird Al', 'George Lopez']]];
Console.log(table[0]) //Returns the array ['Fruits', 'Veggies', 'SomethingElse']
```

This can be useful, but you may want your column names to be the first element in your array like so:

```
var table = [['Fruits', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach'], ['Veggies', 'Carrot', 'Cucumber', 'Raddish'], ['SomethingElse', ['Animals', 'People'], ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'Bear'], ['Weird Al', 'George Lopez']]];
Console.log(table[0]) //Returns the array ['Fruits', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Peach']
```

This is probably want you'll want.  Now to access things is pretty easy!

```
var Fruits = table[0]  //For simplicity
console.log(Fruits[0]) //Fruits
console.log(Fruits[1]) //Apple
console.log(Fruits[2]) //Banana
same as 
console.log(table[0][0])
console.log(table[0][1])
console.log(table[0][2])
```

And there's your n-Dimensional Array!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to reference multiple column values in your `description`. Best I can tell this is just basic string concatenation.

So lets take the elements you want and merge them into one string and at least avoid a whole bunch of `+`'s. Whether you want them to appear delimited on the same line or on separate lines is up to you. Just need to change the value in the join.

```js
var description = [row[6],row[8],row[9]].join('\n')
```

Or if you want them on the same line

```js
var description = [row[6],row[8],row[9]].join(' ')
```

I am not aware of any jagged notation to call multiple non sequential elements in one shot. We just make a new array so that we can call join.